# How clear GetValidationErrors to perform a SaveChange()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-migrations

I just want to perform a SaveChange even if I have an error into GetValidationErrors because of DataAnnotations. In my scenario, user can create a tender with a futur end publishing date. When the end date is in the past, user have the choice to cancel or select a bid. Into this specific scenario, if user want to cancel, I need to update the tender but I can't because the end date is in the past.

So I need your help to do that.

I use C#, MVC4, repository pattern + generic, Code first migration

Thank you very much!!

Karine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

That it's!